# Pandas dataframe join on all elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to join two dataframes in pandas.
One dataframe contains URLs in a column, which contains duplicates ( same values repeating).

Second dataframe contains some properties of those URLs, but unique URLs only, no duplicates.

I am trying to map back or join two dataframes where I get those properties of URLs in 1st dataframe, for all occurances of the URls.

Example :
Dataframe1 : [image: 1st Dataframe with URLs repeating]

Dataframe2 : [image: Dataframe where unique URLs from datafram1 with some properties of URLs]

ResultDataframe : [image: resulting dataframe where all repeating occurances of all URLs get the properties mapped against themselves]

How can this be achieved ? Which particular join | concatinate | or merge method to use to combine the dataframes on all rows.

The dataframe above is just example, actual dataframe has like 300+ unique URLs, and 1st dataframe has 10000+ rows.

I have tried inner join and outer join, does not works.

Comment: did you try `how='left'`?

Comment: @enke , yes does not works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example that should be directly applicable.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1,2,3,2,3,1],[7,8,9,10,11,12]),columns=["A","B"])
print(df)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(zip([1,2,3],["foo","baz","bar"]),columns=["A","X"])
print(df2)
df3 = df.join(df2.set_index('A'), on='A')
print(df3)
```

You will use somthing like `dataframe1.join(dataframe2.set_index("url"),on="url")`

Comment: gave the columns but not the data, the data from df2 is missing in dfres
dfres = df1t.join(df2.set_index("url"),on="url")

'url' is the common column

Comment: Also dfres = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='url',right_on='url', how='outer')
Gives the result where two dataframes are placed side by side, one after the other and not matched